# Python .find() to return the end of found string

Tags: python, file

So I want to pick some data out of a text file, which looks like this:

```
##After some other stuff which could change
EASY:[5,500]
MEDIUM:[10,100]
HARD:[20,1000]
EXPERT:[30,2000]
EXTREME:[50,5000]
```

I'm writing a function which uses the difficulty ('EASY' 'HARD' e.t.c) to return the following list. My current code looks like this:

```
def setAI(difficulty):  #difficulty='EASY' or 'HARD' or...e.t.c)
    configFile=open('AISettings.txt')
    config=configFile.read()
    print(config[(config.find(difficulty)):(config.find(']',(config.find(difficulty))))]) #So it will return the chunk between the difficulty, and the next closed-square-bracket after that
```

This produces the following output:

```
>>> HARD:[20,1000
```

I tried fixing it like this:

```
        print(config[(config.find(difficulty)+2):(config.find(']',(config.find(difficulty)+2))+1)])
```

which returns:

```
>>>RD:[20,1000]
```

The issue I'm trying to adress is that I want it to start after the colon, I am aware that I could use the length of the difficulty string to solve this, but is there a simpler way of returning the end of the string when using the .find() command?

P.S:  I couldn't find any duplicates for this, but it is a slightly odd question, so sorry if it's already on here somewhere; Thanks in advance

EDIT:  Thanks for the replies, I think you basically all solved the problem, but the chosen answer was becasue I like the iteration line-by-line idea, Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the file look like this, why not just iterate line by line and do something like:

```
def setAI(difficulty):  #difficulty='EASY' or 'HARD' or...e.t.c)
    configFile=open('AISettings.txt')
    config=configFile.readlines()
    for line in config:
        if line.startswith(difficulty.upper()):
             print(line[len(difficulty) + 1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Find returns the location. But ranges assume that their end number *should not* be included. Just add one to the end.

```
config = """
##After some other stuff which could change
EASY:[5,500]
MEDIUM:[10,100]
HARD:[20,1000]
EXPERT:[30,2000]
EXTREME:[50,5000]
"""

difficulty = 'HARD'

begin = config.find(difficulty)
end = config.find(']', begin)
print(config[begin:end+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `find` will always give you the position of the first letter of the string. Also consider that the notation `string[start:end]` will give you the substring **including** the character at `start` but **excluding** the character at end. Therefore you could use something like the following:

```
def setAI(difficulty):
    configFile = open('AISettings.txt')
    config = configFile.read()
    start = config.find(difficulty) + len(difficulty) + 1
    end = config.find(']', start) + 1
    print(config[start:end])
```